# Different Encoding in PHP Exec and in command prompt (cmd)

Tags: java, php, encoding, utf-8, cmd

I have this simple PHP Program where it executes a jar that outputs a japanese word:

```
<?php
exec("java -jar PixivClipboardPostGet.jar", $output);
$text = $output[0];
echo $text;
?>
```

And here's the java file:

```
public class PixivClipboardPostGet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
    System.out.println("日本語");
    }
}
```

If I execute it in cmd, it prints the correct Japanese words, with chcp 932:

```
日本語
```

But when I execute it via PHP Exec, here's the output:

```
“ú–{Œê
```

I've tried numerous ways to change the encoding in the PHP so it can output the text correctly:

Attempt 1:

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Output:

```
���{��
```

Attempt 2:

```
$locale='ja-JP.utf-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL,$locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
```

Output:

```
���{��
```

I've tried exec ('chcp') just to know the code page the exec used and it correctly outputs 932, the encoding I set for my cmd.

Can anybody enlighten me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with C# in chinese and resolved by base64 encoding for arguments and response.

PHP

```
// UTF-8 without BOM.
$arg = base64_encode('日本語');
$response = exec("c:\hello.exe {$arg}");
$parse = base64_decode(urldecode($response));
```

C#

```
// Decode the argument to UTF-8
byte[] arg = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
string foo = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(farg);

...

// Output UTF-8 base64 string
byte[] string = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(string)));
```